# A Simple QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qprocess, qtcore

Hi im trying to run a simple QProcess, here is my very basic code.

```
QDir("/home/brett/sweetback");
        QProcess process;
        process.start("mysqldump -uroot -ppass sweetassurfwear > sweetassurfwear.sql");
        process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

What is wrong with this?
I have chaged the code to this

```
QString program = "/usr/bin/mysqldump";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-uroot";
arguments << "-ppass";
arguments << "--routines";
arguments << "sweetassurfwear > sweetassurfwear.sql";
//All the other arguments

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Im now getting the error

```
sweetgui2.cpp: In member function ‘void SweetGuiForm::on_buttonBox_accepted()’:
sweetgui2.cpp:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘QProcess::QProcess(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/usr/include/QtCore/qprocess.h:219: note: candidates are: QProcess::QProcess(const QProcess&)
/usr/include/QtCore/qprocess.h:129: note:                 QProcess::QProcess(QObject*)
make: *** [sweetgui2.o] Error 1
```

I have changed the line

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
to
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
```

It now compiles but im still not getting a dump file

Comment: parent is function in every QObject based class. So either you have to call `parent()` if you want to QProcess become child of current objects parent or `this` if you want QProcess be child of current QObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
arguments << "sweetassurfwear > sweetassurfwear.sql";
```

to:

```
arguments << "sweetassurfwear" << ">" << "sweetassurfwear.sql";
```

You need to handle the different strings as separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

According to Qt Documentation you should do something similar to :

```
QString program = "PathTo/mysqldump";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-uroot";
arguments << "-ppass";
//All the other arguments

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Notice the way you should give your mysqldump app its command line arguments.

Comment: Awsome, but im getting these errors im not sure why                      error: no matching function for call to ‘QProcess::QProcess(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/usr/include/QtCore/qprocess.h:219: note: candidates are: QProcess::QProcess(const QProcess&)
/usr/include/QtCore/qprocess.h:129: note:                 QProcess::QProcess(QObject*)

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the concern in the question.